# Spring AOP, how an annotation on an interface's method can be applied to the implement method?

Tags: annotations, aspectj, java-11, spring-aop, spring5

Is there any way to inherit the annotation annotated in an interface's method?

I am using spring aop to publish some metrics from my controllers. I've created a custom annotation for that purpose. It carries quite much data so the controllers look ugly. I would like to create interfaces to move all the annotations away from the actual business logic. But the method that I use to publish metrics ( annotated with @Around(@annotation(...)) ) cannot catch the annotation when a request comes.